# Trigger hover state in a mixin

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

I've got a Less mixin with a default state and a hover state.
Now I need to activate the hover state in the mixin when I'm hovering over the parent element.

**Less**

```
#icons () {
  .settingsIcon() {
    background: url("settings.png");
    &:hover {
      background: url("settings_hover.png");
    }
  }
}

.SettingsButton {
    height: 50px; 
    width: 200px;
   .icon {
       #icons > .settingsIcon();
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="SettingsButton" >
  <span>Settings</span>
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
```

I need to make sure that the same effect that happens on settingsIcon hover is triggered on the button hover also.
So I think I need to do something like this, where I 'call' the `hover` of `settingsIcon` somehow. Something like this (not valid Less code)

```
.SettingsButton:hover {
  .icon {
     #icons > .settingsIcon():hover;
  }
}
```

How would I do that?

Comment: @Harry [have you not found one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30048985/) [And there was](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283550/792066)

Comment: @Harry well, how you expect that there's "community consensus" if you don't participate? There was a discussion, the interested sides were heard, I'm just applying what those interested parties discussed. (BTW, less tag contains: css preprocessor "less", "less" the opposite of more (the command line tool) and "less" rails)

Comment: @Harry that wouldn't fix the main problem: less means 3 different things. [That shouldn't be allowed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283550/removing-the-less-tag-from-unix-questions-using-the-less-command-good-thing#comment147717_283552) (also   Mooing Duck comment). Do you have any suggestion which allows the problem to be fixed? Mine is: create the 3 needed tags (maybe more, you know, programmers sucks at naming stuff), move the questions to those tags, and burninate plain [less].

Comment: @seven-phases-max [We need \[less\] no more](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293664) BTW, are you willing to retag those questions each time they appear?

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be better to re-write your mixins like in the below example. Essentially we are splitting your base setting and `hover` setting into two different mixins within the same namespace (`#icons()`) and then call them as required.

```css
#icons () {
  .settingsIcon() {
    background: url("settings.png");
  }
  .settingsIconHover(){     
    background: url("settings_hover.png");
  }
}

.SettingsButton {
  height: 50px; 
  width: 200px;
  .icon {
    #icons > .settingsIcon();
    &:hover{
      #icons > .settingsIconHover();
    }
  }
  &:hover .icon{
    #icons > .settingsIconHover();
  }
}
```

---

Another way to achieve this while still maintaining only a single entry in `#icons` for all the states is to move the `.icon` selector also to be within the mixin like in the below snippet.

```css
#icons () {
  .settingsIcon() {
    .icon{
      background: url("settings.png");
    }
    &:hover .icon, & .icon:hover{ /* & here means .SettingsButton */
      background: url("settings_hover.png");
    }
  }
}

.SettingsButton {
  height: 50px; 
  width: 200px;
  #icons > .settingsIcon();
}
```

Comment: I would really prefer to let each icon be represented by a single entry in #icons(), and nest all the states (like hover and active).
Having to define 2 disconnected rules in #icons() just to represent 2 states of the same thing sort of ruins the LESS structure I had in mind

Comment: @Drkawashima: I have added a different version to the answer. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that you can solve this issue by using [`extend`](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature) too.

```
.settingsIcon {
    background: url("settings.png");
    &:hover {
      background: url("settings_hover.png");
    }
}


.SettingsButton {
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    &:extend(.settingsIcon all);
    .icon {
       &:extend(.settingsIcon all);
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
.settingsIcon,
.SettingsButton,
.SettingsButton .icon {
  background: url("settings.png");
}
.settingsIcon:hover,
.SettingsButton:hover,
.SettingsButton .icon:hover {
  background: url("settings_hover.png");
}
.SettingsButton {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Notice that the above generate a not used `.settingsIcon` selector in your CSS. Cause Less does not enable you to extend mixins (see: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1177) which do not output, you can only solve this by putting the `.settingsIcon` declaration in a different file a `@import` that file by using the `reference` keyword:

settingsicon.less:

```
.settingsIcon {
    background: url("settings.png");
    &:hover {
      background: url("settings_hover.png");
    }
}
```

project.less:

```
@import (reference) "settingsicon.less";
.SettingsButton {
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    &:extend(.settingsIcon all);
    .icon {
       &:extend(.settingsIcon all);
    }
}
```

Now compiling `project.less` generates:

```
.SettingsButton,
.SettingsButton .icon {
  background: url("settings.png");
}
.SettingsButton:hover,
.SettingsButton .icon:hover {
  background: url("settings_hover.png");
}
.SettingsButton {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

--

NB aren't you looking for [CSS for hover that includes all child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137449/css-for-hover-that-includes-all-child-elements) in the first place?

**update**
@harry wrote:

> My understanding was that the same background needed to be applied for .SettingsButton:hover .icon and .SettingsButton .icon:hover only.

I think that makes sense. You can do that by using extend too, but i also agree that extending the same class twice is not so DRY too.

With `settingsicon.less`  being again:

```
.settingsIcon {
    background: url("settings.png");
    &:hover {
      background: url("settings_hover.png");
    }
}
```

You can use:

```
@import (reference) "settingsicon.less";
.SettingsButton {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  &.icon {
  &:extend(.settingsIcon);
  }
  &:hover, & .icon:hover {
  &:extend(.settingsIcon:hover);
  }
}
```

or:

```
@import (reference) "settingsicon.less";
.SettingsButton {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  & .icon {
  &:extend(.settingsIcon all);
  }
  &:hover {
  &:extend(.settingsIcon:hover);
  }
}
```

which both compile into:

```
.SettingsButton.icon {
  background: url("settings.png");
}
.SettingsButton:hover,
.SettingsButton .icon:hover {
  background: url("settings_hover.png");
}
.SettingsButton {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Extending all within `.SettingsButton` would result in it getting the background also (which I think is not desired). Extending just the `:hover` would probably be a better alternate :)

Comment: @harry, yes i think you're right about that, but i understand the question asks for two times the background? For the same reason i also refer to the other question.

Comment: Hmm, might be. I think we should leave it to OP to clarify. My understanding was that the same background needed to be applied for `.SettingsButton:hover .icon` and `.SettingsButton .icon:hover` only.